# TSQL NOT EXISTS Why is this query so slow?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, performance, exists

Debugging an app which queries SQL Server 05, can't change the query but need to optimise things.

Running all the selects seperately are quick <1sec, eg: select * from acscard, select id from employee... When joined together it takes 50 seconds.

Is it better to set uninteresting accesscardid fields to null or to '' when using EXISTS?

```
  SELECT * FROM ACSCard
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
     ( SELECT Id FROM Employee 
              WHERE Employee.AccessCardId = ACSCard.acs_card_number )
    AND NOT EXISTS
     ( SELECT Id FROM Visit 
               WHERE Visit.AccessCardId = ACSCard.acs_card_number ) 
  ORDER by acs_card_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have indexes on Employee.AccessCardId, Visit.AccessCardId, and ACSCard.acs_card_number?

Comment: This should be a comment on the original question... Not an answer.

Comment: Indexes resolved the problem - can't believe they wern't there from the beginning!

Answer (score 2):

The SELECT clause is not evaluated in an EXISTS clause.  This:

```
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1/0
               FROM EMPLOYEE)
```

...should raise an error for dividing by zero, but it won't.  But you need to put something in the SELECT clause for it to be a valid query - it doesn't matter if it's NULL or a zero length string.

In [SQL Server, NOT EXISTS (and NOT IN) are better than the LEFT JOIN/IS NULL approach if the columns being compared are not nullable (the values on either side can not be NULL)](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).  The columns compared should be indexed, if they aren't already.